# How to run the same Bitbucket Pipeline with different environment variables for different branches?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a monorepo project that is deployed to 3 environments - testing, staging and production. Deploys to testing come from the `next` branch, while staging and production from the `master` branch. Testing deploys should run automatically on every commit to next (but I'm also fine with having to trigger them manually), but deploys from the master branch should be triggered manually. In addition, every deploy may consist of a client push and server push (depending on the files changed). The commands to deploy to each of the hosts are exactly the same, the only thing changing is the host itself and the environment variables.

Therefore I have 2 questions:

1. Can I make Bitbucket prompt me the deployment target when I manually trigger the pipeline, thus basically letting me choose the set of the env variables to inject into the set sequence of commands? I've seen a screenshot for this in a tutorial, but I lost it and can't find it since.
2. Can I have parallel sequences of commands? I'd like the server and the client push to run simultaneously, but both of them have different steps. Or do I need to merge those into the same step with multiple scripts to achieve that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is 'Yes'.

1. The feature that makes it possible is called `custom` pipelines. [Here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/) is a neat doc that demonstrates how to use them.
2. There is a `parallel` keyword which you can use to define parallel steps. Check out [this doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-or-run-parallel-steps/) for details.

If I'm not misinterpreting the description of your setup, your final pipeline should look very similar to this:

```yaml
pipelines:
  custom:
    deploy-to-staging-or-prod: # As you say the steps are the same, only variable values will define the destination.
       - variables:            # List variable names under here, and Bitbucket will prompt you to supply their values.
          - name: VAR1
          - name: VAR2
       - parallel:
          - step:
              - ./deploy-client.sh 
          - step:
              - ./deploy-server.sh 

  branches:
    next:
      - step:
          script:
            - ./deploy-to-testing.sh
```

---

**UPD**

If you need to use Deployments instead of providing each variable separately, use can utilise `manual` type of trigger:

```yaml
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &RunTests
        script:
          - ./run-tests.sh
    - step: &DeployFromMaster
        script:
          - ./deploy-from-master.sh

pipelines:
  branches:
    next:
      - step:
          script:
            - ./deploy-to-testing.sh
    master:
      - step: *RunTests
      - parallel:
        - step:
            <<: *DeployFromMaster
            deployment: staging
            trigger: manual
        - step:
            <<: *DeployFromMaster
            deployment: production
            trigger: manual
```

Key docs for understanding this pipeline is still [this one](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/) and [this one](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) for yaml anchors. Keep in mind that I introduced a 'RunTests' step on purpose, as

> Since a pipeline is triggered on a commit, you can't make the first step manual.

It will act as a stopper for the deploy step which can only be manual due to your requirements.

Comment: Sweet, that's about what I was leaning towards. I would only like it to prompt me for the deployment environment instead of the full variable list for the custom one. Maybe I could make it a variable and supply it to the `deployment`..? I'll try that

Comment: I like your idea! Not sure if it will work though. Bitbucket Pipelines tend to have rather unexpected limitations when it comes to variable substitution. For example, you must hardcode the image name used as your build environment. But if you manage to do what you said, that will be a cool trick.

Comment: unfortunately you can't supply deployment value as a variable... Too bad

Comment: @JaffParker I had a second thought on your setup and updated my answer.